# Magento 2.3: If click edit product it generates an error

Tags: magento2, product-edit

I'm using Magento2.3. if click edit product it throws this error

> [ There has been an error processing your request Exception printing
>   is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 536178908660 ]

Comment: Change into developer mode

Comment: Then it shows exactly error

Comment: use this command to set developer mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: Or open the file in var/report/536178908660 and you'll have the real error.

Answer (score 0):

To see errors either enable developer mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Or open the error file according to the number printed at

```
var/report/536178908660
```

Open with any text editor.